# Circular Helicoid

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

A helicoid has the following parametric equation:

$$
r(u,v)=\left \langle v\cos u,v\sin u,cu \right \rangle,\qquad u,v,c\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

In ruled form,

$$r(u,v)=\alpha(u)+v\Lambda(u),$$

it has the directrix and the rulings

$$\begin{align}
\alpha(u)&=\left \langle 0,0,cu \right \rangle,\\
\Lambda(u)&=\left \langle \cos u,\sin u,0 \right \rangle,
\end{align}$$

respectively.

I want to create a circular helicoid whose directrix is not a vertical line but a circle,

$$
\alpha(u)=\left \langle R\cos u,R\sin u,0 \right \rangle,
$$

and whose rulings rotate on the plane spanned by $\left \langle -\cos t,-\sin t,0 \right \rangle$ and $\left \langle 0,0,1 \right \rangle$ and not on the plane spanned by $\left \langle 1,0,0 \right \rangle$ and $\left \langle 0,1,0 \right \rangle$.

I need a hint on how to begin approaching this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a>b>0$. Then
$$\gamma_m:\quad \theta\mapsto \left\{\eqalign{\rho&:= a+ b\cos\theta \cr z&:=b\sin\theta\cr}\right.\qquad(0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi)$$
is a circle of radius $b$ in an (abstract) $(\rho, z)$ meridian half-plane. The center of $\gamma_m$ is at distance $a$ from the $z$-axis. We rotate this circle around the $z$-axis by introducing a second rotation variable $\phi$ and letting $$x=\rho\cos\phi, \quad y=\rho\sin\phi\qquad(0\leq\phi\leq 2\pi)\ .$$ In this way we get a parametric representation of a torus $T\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ whose "soul radius" is $a$ and whose "thickness radius" is $b$:
$$T: \quad [0,2\pi]^2\to{\mathbb R}^3\ ,\qquad (\theta,\phi)\mapsto\left\{\eqalign{x&=(a+b\cos\theta)\cos\phi \cr y&=(a+b\cos\theta)\sin\phi\cr z&=b\sin\theta\cr}\right.\quad .$$
You obtain a "helicoidal curve" $\gamma_h$ on this torus if you keep $\phi$ as parameter running from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and let $\theta$ be a *fixed linear function* of $\phi$. Thereby you have to introduce an extra parameter $k\ne0$ which dictates how fast $\gamma_h$ winds around $T$ as $\phi$ varies. Up to a  fixed rotation around the $z$-axis the resulting parametric representation of $\gamma_h$ is  given by
$$\gamma_h:\quad {\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}^3\ ,\qquad \phi\mapsto\left\{\eqalign{x&=\bigl(a+b\cos(k\phi)\bigr)\cos\phi \cr y&=\bigl(a+b\cos(k\phi)\bigr)\sin\phi\cr z&=b\sin(k\phi)\cr}\right.\quad .$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that for each $v$, the intersection of the helicoid with a coaxial cylinder (spiral) in cylindrical coordinates $(v,u,z)$ has the equation $z=u$, or more generally $z=\alpha u$; i.e., a "straight line through the origin".

Therefore, it makes sense to define a "circular helicoid" in *[toroidal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Geometry)* coordinates $(r,u,v)$ by the equation $v=\alpha u$.

$$\begin{aligned}x= & \left(R+r\cos\alpha u\right)\cos u\\
y= & \left(R+r\cos\alpha u\right)\sin u\\
z= & r\sin\alpha u
\end{aligned}$$

[image]

Comment: funnily enough if you replace the expression for $z$ with $r\sin\alpha u +\beta u$ you get something that looks like a "helicoidal helicoid"

Answer (score 3):

Lemme take out one of my old Gravatars first:

[image: bent helicoid]

---

William Meeks and Matthias Weber, in [a paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00208-007-0120-4), construct what they call a "bent helicoid" by applying [Björling's formula](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Bj%C3%B6rling_problem&oldid=31757) to a circle, with a rotationally varying normal field.

For reference, here is a parametric representation of this minimal surface:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\Re\left(\cos z-\frac{i}{k^2-1}(k\cos z\cos kz-k+\sin z\sin kz)\right)\\\Re\left(\sin z-\frac{i}{k^2-1}(k\cos kz\sin z-\cos z\sin kz)\right)\\\Re\left(\frac{i}{k}\sin kz\right)\end{pmatrix}$$

where $z=x+iy$ and $k$ is a parameter that controls the number of "twists". A particularly interesting special case of this is $k=\frac12$, which yields a minimal surface with the topology of a Möbius strip.

Comment: Are you sure this is the parametric representation of the surface ? I get an almost flat surface when I draw it with this formula.

Comment: @Stéphane, what were you using to draw it? I used *Mathematica* for mine. Did you also remember that `Re` means to take the real part of the complex expression?

Comment: I'm using the R package rgl (based on OpenGL). Yes I know for the real part. What do you take for the range of $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: @Stéphane, for the particular picture above, I took $k=10$ and $-\pi\le x\le \pi$, $-\frac14\le y\le\frac14$. I also made sure that the surface was sampled very finely.

Comment: Yes, thanks ! It is nice with these ranges.

Comment: It really looks like a [twisted Möbius strip](https://i.imgur.com/ccln1Ln.png). Isn't it the same ?

Comment: @Stéphane, I don't have my copy of the Meeks-Weber paper at the moment, but IIRC the minimal surface is nonorientable if $k$ is half an odd integer.

Comment: Ok. An animation for fun: https://thumbs.gfycat.com/TalkativeScientificIriomotecat-size_restricted.gif